# Install ubuntu with nvidia drivers

Tags: installation, drivers

How to install Ubuntu without nouveau drivers but with selected driver like nvidia-325?

Answer (score 0):

1) Download your graphics driver from http://www.geforce.com/drivers
2) Press Ctrl + Alt + F5
3) Login with your user
4) Type sudo -i
5) When prompt type your super user password (Basically your password)
6) Now stop your graphics by typing: service lightdm stop
7) Change directory to your nvidia driver installation: cd $home && cd Downloads
8) Change nvidia drivers permission: chmod 777 NVIDIA*.run
9) Now execute the installation: ./NVIDIA*.run
10) Follow all steps: Install 32bit libs, Make auto config Xorg by NVIDIA Installation, etc...
11) If you don't get any errors by nvidia drivers installer reboot your system and enjoy
 
12) Last step is optional: Open up Unity apps menu and look for Nvidia, when you find it open it to check that everything is installed well.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I installed standard packages after first boot to get graphics working. I'm looking for a way to automate this process - ideal would be to make selection during installation since there are alternatives in standard repository.